# missing code cell number after changing theme

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

after changing my theme in jupyter notebook [see here](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes), I no longer have `In[]` and `out[]` number , How can I fix it?

I used this:

```
!pip install jupyterthemes
!jt -t onedork -fs 95 -altp -tfs 11 -nfs 115 -cellw 88% -T -N -kl
```

now my jupyter is something like this:

[image: no number for In[]]
[image]

Comment: Either you need to change the color of this characteristic or use another one. Looking at the screenshots of the github page it is the default behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove "**-altp**" from your line. I believe that is what hides the code cell numbers.

This is the line I used to use:

```
jt -t onedork -T -N -kl -tfs 12 -nfs 12 -cellw 50%
```

This is the line I found online that I recently tried:

```
jt -t onedork -fs 95 -altp -tfs 11 -nfs 115 -cellw 60% -T
```

This is the one that I use now which looks nice and shows code cell numbers:

```
jt -t onedork -T -N -kl -fs 95 -tfs 11 -nfs 115 -cellw 60%
```

I added "**-altp**" and the numbers disappeared! So, just don't add it and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have the seem question but i resolved with this:

```py
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.prompt_container { width:100px !important; }</style>"))
```

Waiting for a real answer